# Cannot call a function using hooks in another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The logout function is used to log out a user by making an API call and deleting this user's information from LocalStorage and from the Redux store. This function therefore uses two hooks: useDispatch and useFetch (custom hook)

```js
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {disconnectUser} from 'store/authentication/authentication.slice'
import useFetch from 'api/useFetch'
import {routes} from 'routes/url'

type ResponseAPI = Record<string, never>

function logout(): void {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const {call: disconnect} = useFetch<ResponseAPI>('auth/logout', {
    fetchOnLoad: false,
    method: 'POST',
  })

  disconnect()
    ?.then(() => {
      dispatch(disconnectUser())
      localStorage.removeItem('authenticated')
      localStorage.removeItem('decodedId')
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      localStorage.removeItem('username')
      location.replace(routes.login)
    })
    .catch(error => Promise.reject(error))

  return
}

export default logout
```

I want to use this logout function in a button, as soon as the user clicks on the Logout button, it will be logged out.

```js
const LogoutButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Button action={() => logout()}>Logout</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LogoutButton
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Do you have any ideas ?
A big thank-you

Comment: The error message says it all: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component, and `function logout(): void` is not a component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logout is not a function it's the hook, and you can't use hook inside the function, because when you do `action={() => logout()}` you are wrapping hook inside the function. Which is not valid in the function component.

```
<Button action={logout}>Logout</Button>
```

Another Way

```
function useLogout() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { call: disconnect } =
    useFetch <
    ResponseAPI >
    ("auth/logout",
    {
      fetchOnLoad: false,
      method: "POST",
    });

  const logout = () => {
    disconnect()
      ?.then(() => {
        dispatch(disconnectUser());
        localStorage.removeItem("authenticated");
        localStorage.removeItem("decodedId");
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("username");
        location.replace(routes.login);
      })
      .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
  };

  return { logout };
}

// Component
const LogoutButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { logout } = useLogout();
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Button action={() => logout()}>Logout</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```